# Edit values in df column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to edit the values in a pandas dataframe by comparing the values that are in the column to a dictionary, and then changing the value in the column according to the value in the dictionary. This would be applied to around 10,000 data points in the single column, so I would rather not iterate through every row, but every value in the columns should change according to its initial value, so what can I do to facilitate that? My initial code is below:

```
ctqparam = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   val = str(row['Subtest'])
   if val in ctqparam_dict.keys():
       ctqparam += [ctqparam_dict[val]]
df.insert(4, column='ctqparam', value = ctqparam)
df = df.drop(columns=['Subtest'])
```

where the ctqparam_dict is the dictionary that I am comparing the value from the columns to. I create an array of values, and then insert it into the df, dropping the initial column in the process. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you give a small example of the dataframe you're starting with and what the expected output should be?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, try something like this...

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

adict = {'one':'wasONE', 'three':'wasTHREE'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'Subtest':['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']})

df = df.replace({'Subtest': adict})
```

**Outputs for each would be:**

```
{'one': 'wasONE', 'three': 'wasTHREE'} 

   col1 Subtest
0     1     one
1     2     two
2     3   three
3     4    four 

   col1   Subtest
0     1    wasONE
1     2       two
2     3  wasTHREE
3     4      four
```